# Paperclip files not being attached to actionmailer. No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, actionmailer

I am trying to attach a paperclip avatar image to an email, however it doesn't seem to realize it is an image that I am attaching, but when I place the url in my browser it finds the image. I am not sure if it is because of the random numbers that paperclip has at the end or not.

In my Usermailer

```
attachments.inline['avatar.jpg'] = File.read("localhost:3000#{@user.avatar.url(:medium)}")
```

In my email

```
<%= image_tag attachments['avatar.jpg'].url %>
```

The url it spits out is(The picture is a random stock photo for testing)

```
localhost:3000/system/users/avatars/000/000/026/medium/Maximus_Minimus_food_truck_Seattle_Washington.JPG?1397942965
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your template statement `<%= image_tag attachments['avatar.jpg'].url -%>`. There is an extra dash in the closing %> statement.

Comment: yep sorry. wasn't in my code. I should have copied and pasted. I must have accidentally hit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Asset pipeline to attached the actual file path. Have not tested.

`"#{Rails.root}/#{<YourAppName>::Application.assets.find_asset('avatar.jpg').pathname}"`

[You can find the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854243/asset-url-in-mailer-on-rails-3-1)

Comment: The problem with this is I would need to know the actual filename. I don't know the filenames for people that upload their avatars. I am only saving the attachment as `avatar.jpg`. Not finding a file `avatar.jpg`

Comment: I had though `paperclip` renames the file? Or at least persists the path/location of it? May be wrong.

Comment: no that url that it spits out `localhost:3000/system/users/avatars/000/000/026/medium/Maximus_Minimus_food_truck_Seattle_Washington.JPG?1397942965`

Comment: How about this `user.avatar.path`? [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984604/get-server-file-path-with-paperclip)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my model looks like

```
class Petition < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :contract
end
```

In mailer, I attached this contract file like this. Hope this helps.

```
def send_invitation(petition)
  attachments[petition.contract_file_name] = File.read(petition.contract.path)
  mail(
    to:       @petition.email,
    subject: t('mailer.send_invitation')) do |format|
    format.html { render 'send_invitation' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to use

`attachments.inline['avatar.jpg'] = @user.avatar.data`